# The Equation of a Tangent Line to a Circle at a Point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, circles, geometric-topology

How do you determine the equation of the tangent line to the circle
$(x-4)^2 + (y+3)^2 = 25$ at $P(8,-6)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First differentiate the equation to get an expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. This will give you the slope of the tangent line at any point $(x,y)$. Then use this and the point $P$ to calculate the equation of the tangent line that passes through $P$.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how to do this? Sorry, but it would be a great help, thanks.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: Nope, I have not.

Answer (score 3):

Hint (without any differential calculus):

(1) The slope of the line joining points $\;(x_1,y_1)\;,\;(x_2,y_2)\;,\;\;x_1\neq x_2\;$ ,  is $\;\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2} \;$.

(2) Two (non-vertical) lines with slopes $\;m_1\,,\,\,m_2\;$ are perpendicular to each other if and only if $\;m_1m_2=-1\;$ .

(3) The tangent line to a point on a circle is perpendicular to the circle's radius at that point .

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $2(x-4) + 2(y+3)y' = 0 \to y'|_{(8,-6)} = -\dfrac{x-4}{y+3}|_{(8,-6)}= \dfrac{4}{3}$. Can you continue using the point-slope equation ?

Comment: Could you explain why you multiplied each bracket by 2?

Comment: That comes from the chain rule.

Comment: @BRIC-Fan I don't think this user is at that level yet?

Answer (score 1):

The vector that has origin at the center of the circle $O$ and ends at $P$ is orthogonal to $\vec{PM}$ where $M(x,y)$ is a point of the tangent. So we have $\vec{OP}\cdot\vec{PM}=0$ and this means
$$(8-4)(x-8)+(-6+3)(y+6)=0$$ and this gives the tangent equation
$$4x-3y=50$$

Comment: You made an arithmetic mistake.  $4 \cdot -8 + -3 \cdot 6 = -32 - 18 = -50$, so $4x - 3y = 50$.

Comment: Could you explain how you calculated 50? I understand the process to calculate the other two values; however, I am having trouble understanding the calculation of 50.

Comment: -32-18=-50 thanks N.F.Taussig

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now. Thanks for the response

Comment: If you calculated -50, why did you put a positive version of it in the final answer?

Comment: The equation was $4x-3y-50=0$ and this is equivalent to $4x-3y=50$

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you, I understand now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

we will use the quadratic equation, in particular, the fact that $ax^2 + bx+c = 0$ has repreat roots if and only if the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac = 0.$

pick a line through $P=(8, -6)$ with slope $m$ given by $$y = m(x-8) - 6 \tag 1$$
this line cuts the circle at $$(x-4)^2 + \left(m(x-8) - 6 + 3 \right)^2 = 25$$ it is easier to make change a variable here $x - 8 = u.$ with that we get the quadratic equation $$0 = (u+4)^2 + (mu-3)^2 - 25 = (1 + m^2)u^2 +(8-6m)u$$ and the discriminant is $$(8 - 6m)^2 = 0 \to m = \frac 43$$

the tangent line is $$y = \frac 43 (x-8) + 6 $$

ps. now i can see that the point $(8, -6)$ is on the circle. had i noticed that it would have far easier to find the tangent to a circle at a point on it than from a point outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without calculus, and simply noting that the equation of the circle suggests an elementary application of Pythagoras may be helpful, draw a diagram.

In particular note that the point $(0,0)$ lies on the circle and that the point $(8,-6)$ is diametrically opposite.

The tangent is perpendicular to the diameter, and you can either use this to get the slope, or use similar triangles to find the $x$-intercept of the tangent. In the first case you have a point and a gradient. In the second case you have two points. In either case you have enough to determine the equation of the tangent.